How can I display DWG custom file properties in the file explorer window
I need to be able to view the custom properties values of my AutoCAD file on the windows file explorer details columns.
I can write to the custom properties, but the files are usually named according to BS ISO 19650, which may not make sense to all my potential users. 
in the example image, The Name, Status, Type, are visible, but not the Title or Date Locked.
I have enabled all the other view details, but to no avail.
I am expected to see the File's custom properties in the  file explorer columns options.
